# Finding the minimum value of a function.

Tags: functions

Find the minimum value of the function:

$$f(x) = \frac{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^6-\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2 - 2}{\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^3 +\left(x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}\right)}$$

for $x>0$.

I know that this function simplifies into something a little 'nicer' than what we have above. However, I have hit a brick wall after that. Please refrain from using derivatives to find the minimum value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numerator of $f(x)$ is $$
\begin{align}
\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^6-\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2=&\Bigg(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3+\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\Bigg)\times
\\&\Bigg(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\Bigg)\,.
\end{align}$$
Hence, $f(x)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$.  The rest is easy, and the answer is that the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $6$, which is obtained only at $x=1$.

Comment: What's a good way to notice this kind of symmetry in problems?

Comment: I can't answer that question.  There are so many tricks when dealing with inequalities.  The only main idea of this problem is to notice that $\left(x^6+\frac{1}{x^6}\right)+2=\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2$.